# The background color reaches more area if a border is active

Tags: html, css

That's the best title I could come up with, sorry if it's not clear.

I have a table, which has a top-margin. Around that table I have a div, which has a blue background. This blue background only affects the table itself, and doesn't include the margin area (which seems weird considering the margin area should still be inside that div). Yet if I add a border to the div, the whole area (including the margin) gets that background.

```
#table_div {
  background-color: blue;
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
}

#main_table {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Is there any particular reason on why this happens?

To get a background without having to use a border I replaced the margin of the table to the padding of the div. I created this post not to ask how to get it to work, but really to understand what is happening and why it is happening

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/jxbmg4vx/1/

Remove the border lines to see what I mean

Comment: Make a JS fiddle for us to look at. Also, did you look up `<table>`?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jxbmg4vx/1/ Here it is take a look

Comment: Try looking up "Collapsing Margins"....it has the answer.

Comment: I see! Thank you, I will read about that

Comment: Take a look at this - and think about how to ask this a bit differently... https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/jxbmg4vx/21/

Answer (score -1):

This is the CSS feature. 
I have two solutions.

```
#table_div {
  background-color: blue;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

or

```
#table_div {
  background-color: blue;
  padding-top:200px;
}
#main_table {
  margin: auto;
}
```